# NODEJS Marklogic - Write document list cannot process response with 404 status when using documents.write()

Tags: node.js, marklogic

I'm new to nodejs and marklogic, and I'm following a tutorial for a simple app, I have setup and configured my marklogin login credentials,

when I run this sample code by running `node sample.js`

the output is `write document list cannot process response with 404 status`

I wonder why I'm encountering this error,

here is the code from the tutorial,

my-connection.js

```
module.exports = {
    connInfo: {
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 8001,
    user: 'user',
    password: 'password'
    }
};
```

sample.js

```
const marklogic = require('marklogic');
const my = require('./my-connection.js');
const db = marklogic.createDatabaseClient(my.connInfo);
const documents = [
{ uri: '/gs/aardvark.json',
   content: {
    name: 'aardvark',
    kind: 'mammal',
    desc: 'The aardvark is a medium-sized burrowing, nocturnal mammal.'
   }
},
{ uri: '/gs/bluebird.json',
   content: {
    name: 'bluebird',
    kind: 'bird',
    desc: 'The bluebird is a medium-sized, mostly insectivorous bird.'
   }
},
 { uri: '/gs/cobra.json',
  content: { 
    name: 'cobra',
    kind: 'mammal',
    desc: 'The cobra is a venomous, hooded snake of the family Elapidae.'
  }
 },
];

db.documents.write(documents).result(
function(response) {
 console.log('Loaded the following documents:');
 response.documents.forEach( function(document) {
  console.log(' ' + document.uri);
 });
},
function(error) {
 console.log('error here');
 console.log(JSON.stringify(error, null, 2));
}
);
```

I hope someone can tell me what is wrong with the code,

Thank You!

Comment: Have you managed to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The MarkLogic NodeJS Client library is meant to run against a so-called MarkLogic REST-api instance. There is typically one running at port 8000, but you can also deploy other ones at different ports by issuing a POST call to :8002/v1/rest-apis, as described here:

http://docs.marklogic.com/REST/POST/v1/rest-apis

Port 8001 however is reserved for the MarkLogic Admin UI, which doesn't understand the REST calls that the NodeJS Client library is trying to invoke, hence the 404 (not found)..

HTH!