# NodeJS and Marklogic 9 - how to save a json document to the database?

Tags: node.js, marklogic

I'm new to NodeJS and Marklogic, I'm following a tutorial on how to save a json document to the database, but I cannot make it work, is my syntax or code correct?

```
const marklogic = require('marklogic');
const my = require('./my-connection.js');
const db = marklogic.createDatabaseClient(my.connInfo);

const documents = [
{ uri: '/gs/aardvark.json',
content: {
name: 'aardvark',
kind: 'mammal',
desc: 'The aardvark is a medium-sized burrowing, nocturnal mammal.'
}
},
{ uri: '/gs/bluebird.json',
content: {
name: 'bluebird',
kind: 'bird',
desc: 'The bluebird is a medium-sized, mostly insectivorous bird.'
}
}
];

db.documents.write(documents).result(
function(response) {
console.log('Loaded the following documents:');
response.documents.forEach( function(document) {
console.log(' ' + document.uri);
});
},
function(error) {
console.log('error here');
console.log(JSON.stringify(error, null, 2));
}
);
```

I'm getting 404 error on /gs paths, Is the folder and json file created when I execute this command or do i have to manually create it?

Thank You!

Comment: FWIW, the above code works when I run it. Please update your post with the version of ML and Node.js you are using, what platform you're on, and more specifics about the error you got. Also, double check your connection information (the contents of ./my-connection.js).

Comment: the connection parameters I supplied is working, i tried accessing the db and I was able to login using the credentials I set,

the Version of Marklogic Server Installed is 9 , Node Js version is 6.11, the Marklogic Nodejs Client API is 2.0.3

Comment: Are you sure you are not running against 8001, which is not a valid REST-api port? See also your other question and my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48074762/nodejs-marklogic-write-document-list-cannot-process-response-with-404-status-w

Comment: Have you managed to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

When you say you are getting a "404 error on /gs paths", I assume you're saying you cannot read back the documents you inserted. (It would be nice to see the full error).

If you're not authenticating as a user with admin privileges, you need to make sure the documents are readable. The default permissions (which is what are used here since there's no explicit perms) are rest-reader:read and rest-writer:update. You can read more about these roles here:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/node-dev/intro#id_70898